# Angular 2 - Binding vs Subscribing

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that maintains a **context** property

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  // a variable/getter in service that holds context
  _currentContext: any;
  get currentContext() { return this._currentContext;}

  // a method in service that fetches context
  fetchContext() {
    return this._http.get(`/api/xxx`).map(response => response.json());
}
```

Now a component can inject this service, and elements in component template can directly bind to the **context**. These bindings get updated as part of **change detection** whenever context changes.

What if I want to do run some logic in component when context changes?

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-cmp',
    template: `<div *ngIf="_myService.currentContext` >asdf</div>
 })
export class MyComponent{
    constructor(private _myService: MyService) {}

    //doSomethingOnContextChange(){}
}
```

I believe the answer is to create/maintain an **Observable** in my service, and then my component subscribes to that observable.

```js
 _currentContextObservable= new Subject<any>();
 get currentContextObservable(): Observable<any> { return this._currentContextObservable; }
```

So, for each such variable, do I need to maintain one variable/getter and one subject/observable? Or is there any other elegant/better way?

Comment: That's the way to do it.

Comment: For relatively decoupled service it's helpful to maintain both `context` variable and `context$` observable, so you can always choose between them. The appropriateness of `context` depends on whether an observable ought be cold or hot (the example doesn't show where an observable is subscribed but this part but it is quite important).

Comment: use ngrx and define a store with multiple properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use `BehaviorSubject` for this kind of services:

```ts
export class MyService {
    private contextSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    context$ = this.contextSubject.asObservable();

    get context() {
        return this.contextSubject.value;
    }

    ...
}
```

you can use either `context` or `context$` depending on what you need.